# Copy rows from one table to another in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have two tables with the same structure. I need to select data from one table and have to store them into the other.

How can I do that?

Comment: Sadly, MySQL doesn't support SELECT INTO: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since they are the same structure then you can just do

```
insert into table1 select colum1, column2,... from table2
```

Answer (score 17):

```
insert into tablea(id,name) select id,name from tableb;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
insert into blacklist 
select * 
from newblacklist
```

for uploading any single number

```
insert into blacklist 
select * 
from newblacklist 
where numbers ='123456'
```

Answer (score 6):

leave out the values keyword

```
insert into tbl1 
select * from tbl2
```

Comment: you don't want to let the db engine assume field order, be explicit