# How to insert multiple row data into database from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

am currently creating a table in PHP that display all row of data from one of the table in my database. After that, I want to save all row from the PHP's table into new database table. But the problem is, after save, only the last row will be stored into the new table in database, the other row from early will not be save. Can someone help me. I want to try the foreach but can someone teach me.

```
<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td colspan="12"><div align="center">
      <h3><strong>BOOKS</strong></h3>
  </div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="80"><div align="center">Code</div></td>
  <td width="40"><div align="center">No</div></td>
  <td width="250"><div align="center">Name</div></td>
  <td width="100"><div align="center">Publisher</div></td>
  <td width="80"><div align="center">Price</div></td>
  <td width="60"><div align="center">Quantity</div></td>
</tr>

<?php do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
        <input name="student_no" type="hidden" id="student_no" value="<?php echo $row_UserDetails['student_no']; ?>" />
        <input name="book_code" type="text" id="book_code" value="<?php echo $row_book_booking_list['book_code']; ?>" size="8" readonly="readonly" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
        <input name="book_no" type="text" id="book_no" value="<?php echo $row_book_booking_list['book_no']; ?>" size="1" readonly="readonly" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
        <input name="book_name" type="text" id="book_name" value="<?php echo $row_book_booking_list['book_name']; ?>" size="31" readonly="readonly" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
        <input name="book_publisher" type="text" id="book_publisher" value="<?php echo $row_book_booking_list['book_publisher']; ?>" size="10" readonly="readonly" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
        <input name="book_price" type="text" id="book_price" value="<?php echo $row_book_booking_list['book_price']; ?>" size="7" readonly="readonly" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <select name="book_quantity" id="book_quantity">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
      </select>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
<?php } while ($row_book_booking_list = mysql_fetch_assoc($book_booking_list)); ?>
</table>
```

---

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO book_booked_list (student_no, book_code, book_no, book_name, book_publisher, book_price, book_quantity) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['student_no'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['book_code'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['book_no'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['book_name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['book_publisher'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['book_price'], "double"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['book_quantity'], "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_book_con, $book_con);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $book_con) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: So are you trying to copy rows from one database into another?  If that is the case, I would maybe look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821517/how-copy-rows-from-one-table-to-another-table

Comment: I also would avoid mysql and use mysqli instead

Comment: actually, copy the row from one into another but with the updation of the data. To be easy like this, first database table is book table, second database table is for the book that has been booked. 1st table only display what books need to be booked. 2nd table will have all the booked books from each student differentiate by their student number..

Comment: I just need help on the query to allow multiple row saving into database because currently right now only the last row will be saved.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: `sprintf` and hacks like `GetSQLValueString` are unreliable and can lead to severe problems. Update to prepared statements with placeholder values.

Answer (score 3):

To copy all rows from `source_table` to `book_booked_list` table, just execute the query below:

```
INSERT INTO book_booked_list 
    (student_no, book_code, book_no, book_name, book_publisher,
       book_price, book_quantity)
SELECT 
    student_no, book_code, book_no, book_name, book_publisher, 
       book_price, book_quantity
FROM source_table
```

Replace `source_table` with the name of the table you copy data from.

Comment: do I need to change something in here to allow multiple row of saving into databse?

Comment: $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO book_booked_list (student_no,book_code, book_no, book_name, book_publisher,book_price, book_quantity) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s)",                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['student_no'], "int"),                 GetSQLValueString($_POST['book_code'], "text"),                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['book_no'], "text"),                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['book_name'], "text"),

Comment: @black No you don't need to specify values and you don't need to use `$_POST`. Just run the query I gave you after replacing `source_table` with the table you copy from. The DB will handle all everything for you; it will copy all rows from one table to the other.

Answer (score -1):

Your DO...WHILE loop generates input fields with identical names: all student number fields are named "student_no", so only the last set of form values will be kept and sent for processing.

If you want to insert multiple rows, you need to use arrays instead: replace "student_no" with "student_no[]", "book_code" with "book_code[]", etc. Then, on the server side, loop through the arrays to insert each row separately:

```
$stuno = $_POST['student_no'];
$bookcode = $_POST['book_code'];
.... etc...
for($i=0; $i < count($stuno); $i++){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO book_booked_list (student_no, ....) 
    VALUES ($stuno[$i])"
}
```

Of course, there are more efficient ways to do that, and you should sanitize your form values before inserting into your database. This is only to get you started with arrays.

Comment: for($i=0; $i < count($stuno); $i++){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO book_booked_list (student_no, book_code, book_no, book_name, book_publisher, book_price, book_quantity) 
    VALUES ($studentno[$i],$book_code[$i]$book_no[$i]$book_name[$i]$book_publisher[$i]$book_price[$i]$book_quantity[$i])"
  mysql_select_db($database_book_con, $book_con);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($sql, $book_con) or die(mysql_error());
}

Comment: change to this one but error said "unexpected 'mysql_select_db'"